# Windows SendMessage() msg codes

Tags: c#, winapi, user32, msg

I use this code:

```
[DllImport( "User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage" )]
private static extern int SendMessage( IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam );
```

This code sends a message to a specific `HWND`. But I cannot find a list of "msg" codes (2nd parameter) anywhere on the Internet.

Are there any lists with these msg codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of messages that you can send:

1. System-Defined Messages:
   You can find documentations for possible values for messages in multiple websites one of them is [Microsoft SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx), Also [this](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessageList.htm) link may be helpful.
2. Application-Defined Messages: Where an application creates its own messages, however, note that there are some conventions for the message that can be used which are listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx#app_defined).